# Jenkins build job giving error - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, tomcat8

I am trying to build simple Jenkins build job in my local workspace. I have built simple mvc gradle application. Jenkins build job has been setup with required gradel task but getting below error for jmx

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\harshal\.jenkins\workspace\MVCApp
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir C:\Users\harshal\.jenkins\workspace\MVCApp\.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/harshalpatil2012/HelloWorld-MVC-App.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/harshalpatil2012/HelloWorld-MVC-App.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.9.0.windows.1'
 > git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/harshalpatil2012/HelloWorld-MVC-App.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision a7cf612bd16cc92d5e56137284de5318ce9beec2 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git.exe checkout -f a7cf612bd16cc92d5e56137284de5318ce9beec2 # timeout=10
Commit message: "spring gradle demo app"
 > git.exe rev-list --no-walk a7cf612bd16cc92d5e56137284de5318ce9beec2 # timeout=10
[MVCApp] $ C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe -xe C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-8.5.75\temp\jenkins5788250459304119055.sh
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1556]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\harshal\.jenkins\workspace\MVCApp>[Gradle] - Launching build.
[MVCApp] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\harshal\.jenkins\workspace\MVCApp\gradlew.bat clean build && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have disabled jmx as below but still not sure why I am gettign same error in build execution.
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"

I have deployed JENKINS war in my local tomcat 8.5 using intellj

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is some service or process using port 1099. You need to find what process is using that port, then kill/end it (or change the port gradle is using) and rerun your job. I'm not a Windows user but the same principle should follow: Using NetStat.exe you can see the used ports in your machine with their processes. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows) can also help you.

Comment: Yes I did that as well and also tried changing JMX port as well but still giving same error with new JMX port.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the Intellj trying to connect to JMX during startup. I switched to eclipse and Jenins setup was working correctly via my eclipse tomcat server deployment.